# how to write a test to test controller and api so I can run PR checks without database dependency?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sequelize.js, chai, sinon

This is controller code. That post or creates a user. email should be unique and account cannot be created again with same email.

```
    exports.saveUser = (request, response) => {

        const result = (savedUser) => {
            response.status(200);
            response.json(savedUser);
        };

        bcrypt.hash(request.body.user.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
            let user = {
                first_name : request.body.user.firstName,
                last_name : request.body.user.lastName,
                email : request.body.user.email,
                hashed_password : hash
            }
            console.log("conroller")
            const promise = userService.save(user);

            promise
                .then(result)
                .catch(renderErrorResponse(response));
        });

    };
```

This is service layer

```
    'use strict';
    const db = require("./../../models")
    /**
     * Saves the new user object.
     *
     * @param user
     */

    exports.save = (user,result) => {

       return db.User_tbl.create({
            first_name: user.first_name,
            last_name:user.last_name,
            email:user.email,
            hashed_password:user.hashed_password
          })
    }
```

Below is user model

```
    module.exports = (sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
        const user = sequelize.define("User_tbl",{
            first_name:{
                type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
                allowNull:false
            },
            last_name:{
                type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
                allowNull:false
            },
            email:{
                type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
                allowNull:false,
                unique:true
            },
            hashed_password:{
                type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
                allowNull:false
            },
            id:{
                type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey:true,
                autoIncrement: true
            }
        })
        return user;
    }
```

Things I have done include writing test that hit the test db... but this does't work at PR checks as no db at hosting side. Tried mock sequelize but improper documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Context: your function under test is **saveUser**.

Case: user account cannot be created again with the same email. If you want to use Sinon, then, you need to **stub** *userService.save*. You need to define stub which [check argument](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stubwithargsarg1-arg2-) and [define stub's behaviour](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stuboncalln-added-in-v18) on first call (which is success) and on second call (which is failed). Lastly, you need to verify whether your stub [get called twice](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/#spycalledtwice) or at least more than once. I can not provide example because I hardly use jest, but the principle is still the same.

2. Context: you want to test hit test db in test environment but there is no db.

Depends on what DB you use, you can use in-memory db. The practice is turn on / start db before test, and turn off / stop after test. If you use mongodb, you can use [mongodb-memory-server](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server).

Hope this helps.